# Angularjs sharing methods between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was reading [this article](http://code.realcrowd.com/on-the-bleeding-edge-advanced-angularjs-form-validation/) on Angular validation and thought it would be good to use in my own project. It's working really well and I'd like to extend it accessing methods in other controllers upon successful validation of the form. I've tried various ways of doing this but I can't seem to see the methods in the $scope object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.0" 
      data-semver="3.0.0" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.8" 
      data-semver="1.0.8" 
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="rcSubmit.js"></script>
    <script src="loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="loginApp.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
          <h1>Simple Login Form</h1>
          <form name="loginForm" novalidate 
            ng-app="LoginApp" ng-controller="LoginController" 
            rc-submit="login()">
            <div class="form-group"
              ng-class="{'has-error': rc.loginForm.needsAttention(loginForm.username)}">
             <input class="form-control" name="username" type="text" 
              placeholder="Username" required ng-model="session.username" />
             <span class="help-block" 
              ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">Required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"
              ng-class="{'has-error': rc.loginForm.needsAttention(loginForm.password)}">
              <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" 
                placeholder="Password" required ng-model="session.password" />
              <span class="help-block" 
                ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required">Required</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" 
                value="Login" title="Login">
                <span>Login</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was hoping that someone can tell me what I'm missing in order to make this work. I've forked a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/bkxyhO).

Comment: Could you be a little bit more precise about what you're trying to achieve? I don't understand how sharing methods between controllers is related to validation. Usually the way to go with validation is building a directive and accessing the model-controller.

Comment: Hi Hugo, I'm wanting to access some methods I have in a shared service. The service is working fine for other controllers but when I try to use it with this validation code I can access the methods. For instance in the code below how would I be able to access the methods in my service? I've tried everything you can think off but I still get undefined. // define controller for login
var LoginController = ['$scope',
function ($scope) {
 
    $scope.session = {};
 
    $scope.login = function () {
        // process $scope.session
        alert('logged in!');
    };
}];

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be with an angular service. For example:

```
app.factory('svc', function () {
    var msg="original...";
    return {
        setMessage: function(x) {
            msg=x;
        },
        getMessage: function() {
            return msg;
        }
    };
});
```

This way you can access the fucntions inside `svc` in any controller that you inject `svc` into:

```
app.controller("ctrl1",function($scope,svc,$timeout){
  $scope.someText=svc.getMessage();
  $scope.$watch("someText",function(v){
    svc.setMessage(v);
  });
});

app.controller("ctrl2",function($scope,svc){
  $scope.msg=svc.getMessage();
  $scope.$watch(svc.getMessage,function(v){
    $scope.msg=v;
  });
});
```

See [this demo plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzW2rAad6MWUGBRfzkcB?p=preview) (I ignored that plunk you provided because it had a lot of noise).

**EDIT**

Executing the service method and form validation are not really related to each other, [see plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzW2rAad6MWUGBRfzkcB?p=preview).

**EDIT**

If you want to use the services or controllers of one app inside another, just reference the dependencies in your main app and call the services defined in your main app inside your second app. If your main app is called `demoApp1`, then you could create another app called `dempApp2` and reference `demoApp1` in `demoApp2` and use any services defined in `demoApp1` inside `demoApp2`. See the plunk I've updated it to demonstrate what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for answering the question so quickly. I'l give the service a try and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, The service works fine and I'm able to share methods across the application but U still can't see those methods in the validation controller. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by seeing the methods in the validation controller?

Comment: I would like to call a service method once the form has been validated , from here: // define controller for login <code>
var LoginController = ['$scope',
function ($scope) {
 
    $scope.session = {};
 
    $scope.login = function () {
        // process $scope.session
        alert('logged in!');
    };
}]; </code>

Comment: @user686483 I still don't fully understand what you mean, but I've changed the plunk to call the service method only when the form is valid. See the updated the plunk.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I think that the solution that you posted works for an app that has controllers and services in the same app. In my question there are different apps and controllers throughout the application. This means that if I include the service reference in the app and pass it to the controller I get undefined.

Comment: I tried exactly that and nothing worked for me. I ended up just having a regular js function that's called onsubmit. The function picks up the service methods and allows me to execute them. Thank you very much for all you help.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach for you to communicate between the two controllers is to use events.

[Scope Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)

In this check out `$on`, `$broadcast` and `$emit`.

In general use case the usage of `angular.element(catapp).scope()` was designed for use outside the angular controllers, like within jquery events.

Ideally in your usage you would write an event in controller 1 as:

```
$scope.$on("myEvent", function (event, args) {
   $scope.rest_id = args.username;
   $scope.getMainCategories();
});
```

And in the second controller you'd just do

```
$scope.initRestId = function(){
   $scope.$broadcast("myEvent", {username: $scope.user.username });
};
```

Can you try including the `firstApp` module as a dependency to the `secondApp` where you declare the `angular.module`. That way you can communicate to the other app.

Comment: In your example second controller must be child of the first controller. Also if your first controller is not presented on the page, nothing happens.